# Asynchronous Message queue for Perl

Tags: perl, asynchronous, enterprise

Could someone please recommend an Asynchronous message queue that works well with Perl.

I'm not fussed whether it's purely written in perl, it's fine if it is written in something else (c binary etc) and just has a perl client.

Some guidelines I'm looking for:
- Lightweight, not too heavy on resources.
- A minimum amount of dependancies (I don't want to have to install a large amount of libraries just to get it to run).
- It needs to be suitable for enterprise use and have a community+docs where I can get support.

- To set some context, I am notifying a number of people in a Catalyst application, I'm cautious of sending out too many emails at once from the application so was going to use an Asynchronous queue to handle the email sending, and then hopefully not slowing down the user experience.

Comment: Maybe consider using REDIS - I think it is great for this sort of thing and you can `pop()` messages off the queue in Perl, PHP, Python, bash, or any other scripting language. It also does backing store to disk, so if your application crashes, the messages are still retained for later processing.

Comment: Following on... you basically do LPUSH to add messages to the list/queue and LPOP to take things out of the list/queue. Timeouts are also available. Or use SADD to add to a set and SREM to remove messages from a set. Until you get started, in Perl, if your message queue is called `MESSAGES`, you can just do `echo LPUSH MESSAGES EmailAddress | redis-cli` and later add client libraries to do it faster.

Comment: How many people?  I have a low use system using a work queue, and i just implemented it as a db table and enqueue/dequeue operations.  if your throughput is relatively low, this means you don't have to add yet another tool to your tool with its own maintenance needs into your app.

Answer (score 2):

For an similar thing (enqueue, process, send-email) I'm using [IPC::DirQueue](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::DirQueue).

I choosed it because:

- it uses atomic file operation, so no database needed
- can have multiple enqueue processes
- and multiple dequeue processes too (on the same FIFO-like queue)

simple *enqueue* script

```
use 5.014;
use warnings;
use IPC::DirQueue;

my $dq = IPC::DirQueue->new({ dir => "./qq" });
foreach my $n (1..10) {
    $dq->enqueue_string("some string $n");
}
```

and and simple dequeue

```
use 5.014;
use warnings;
use IPC::DirQueue;
use Path::Tiny;

my $dq = IPC::DirQueue->new({ dir => "./qq" });
while(my $job = $dq->wait_for_queued_job(0, 2) ) {
    my $content = path($job->get_data_path())->slurp; 
    say $content;
    $job->finish();
}
```

Similar module is the [Directory::Queue](https://metacpan.org/pod/Directory::Queue).

As usually ... your mileage ... :) Maybe some more experienced perl developers will recommed you an better solution.

Comment: I've been using Directory::Queue for years without an issue.

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to make some use of Gearman for a message queue; you can then use [`Net::Async::Gearman`](http://metacpan.org/module/Net::Async::Gearman) to talk to it fully asynchronously, both as a Client (to submit jobs) and as a Worker (to perform them).