# Send a message (or packet) to another trusted machine and have it buffer the message until process is ready

Tags: linux, tcp, udp, nic

I have two trusted machines that are connected, call them 192.168.0.10 and 192.168.0.11. Let's assume both machines are running Linux. Is it **possible** for me to send a message from 192.168.0.10 to 192.168.0.11 and have 192.168.0.11 buffer that message (for some TTL) until a process on 192.168.0.11 starts listening to the port that message was sent to?

I understand the current state of the world. Assuming I have a C server and if we wanted to have 192.168.0.10 send a message to 192.168.0.11, we would have 192.168.0.11 create a socket, bind that socket to an address and port, listen for connections, accept connections and receive messages using recv. And 192.168.0.10 would create a socket, connect and send using send. I am specifically wondering can the client (in this case 192.168.0.10) send the message before the server (192.168.0.11) starts listening for connections?

[Image of what I would like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/diivI.png)

Comment: Without some kind of kernel hack, no.  What should be happening is that the client resends periodically until it gets a response.

Comment: I understand that this would most likely need to be done at the kernel level. Do you have any pointers for what all needs to be done for something like this to exist?

Comment: Maybe you should try the simple approach first: have the client attempt to reconnect until it succeeds.

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question. I know having the client poll to see if the server is available is an option.

Comment: And it is by far the simpler option, so try that first.

Comment: You'll have the same problem if the destination host is down or off the network, so you need to handle reconnections anyway.

Comment: For context, I am a researcher trying to figure out what is possible. I am NOT a programmer just trying to "get it done." That is why I specifically asked if it's *possible*. This might not be the correct forum. If it's not please suggest a better place to ask this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to WiKi, "Remote direct memory access ([RDMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_direct_memory_access)) is a direct memory access from the memory of one computer into that of another without involving either one's operating system."

This page further says, "... enabling the network adapter to transfer data from the wire directly to application memory or from application memory directly to the wire"

To use RDMA, the applications use a well-defined API to transfer data. This certainly would fit the bill in the sense that "it is possible for to send a message from 192.168.0.10 to 192.168.0.11 and have 192.168.0.11 buffer that message" provided the OS and the network adapters support it. See [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_direct_memory_access) for the traction RDMA has gained with hardware and software vendors.

Comment: But not in the sense "buffer that message (for some TTL) until a process ... starts listening". RDMA is intended to speed up the transfer from a high speed network adapter into user memory to offload the CPU and approach DMA speeds. This approach still requires a host application to be listening in advance. It definitely does not provide the semantics shown in the linked message sequence chart.

Answer (score 1):

Both TCP and UDP messages are delivered to a process listening to a specific port (or port pair). If a datagram is received and no process is listening, it is discarded.

You are describing a publish-subscribe, or otherwise queueing solution that requires storage somewhere. The operating system does not provide these services and you would need to include a message bus or queueing system in your landscape to support this persistence.

For example, what do you expect to happen if the receiving system restarts after receiving a message, but before the process starts to listen?

Comment: Hello Mr. could you please show me how I can do this in Perl?

Comment: You could look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25247144/asynchronous-message-queue-for-perl (Asynchronous Message queue for Perl) for possible suggestions.